# Switching language: display alternative or active first?

Tags: navigation, language, component

What is the best practices to display and switch between two languages. For example, I'm at *website.com/en/* and I want to switch in french (*website.com/fr/*). Do you think I should display the active language first or propose the other language available first?

[image: language widget]
For me, I think we should show the active state because it's the pattern that most user are accustomed. What do you think?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only have two options then a dropdown is pointless complexity. Replace your current implementation with a link such as "view this page in English" or the French alternative when the page is rendered with English text.

Answer (score 2):

Show the current state. With the control minimized, it acts as a label.

(And what would you do if you had more than 2 languages?)